# How to determine hardware/software compatibility?

Tags: shields, hardware

Currently, I'm using [Greiman's SdFat Library](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat) with [Adafruit's Data logging Shield](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1141).

I'm thinking about switching to the [Adafruit micro SD Card Breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/product/254). I imagine that it will work as both products are made by Adafruit, and the board schematics *look* similar. However, I don't know what to look at to be sure they are the same.

Is it enough that they both use the [HC4050M](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Toshiba/74HC4050DBJ?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuiiWkaIwCK2VGJzXkUQsJSbMju57F4ABI%3d) chip, or is there something else that I need to be aware of?

Short of buying one and testing it. What do I need to look at to verify that these two boards will work with the library?

Comment: A difficult question.  Any list would only be good if it were maintained, perhaps, monthly at the slowest.  Unfortunately, the obvious solution is likely the most difficult.  That is, to analyze the chip specifications used on each board and compare that with the source code in the intended to be used libraries.  That, or the hardware is usually cheap enough that trying to see if it works is also an option.  I should add that the schematic of the board and any non-volatile configuration data (like the address of an I2C chip) should also be considered.

Comment: look at example code if it is available

Comment: Will it work in principle? I'd say it is safe to assume it will. Will it work with your code? The easiest way to answer that is to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HC4050M is just used for logic level translation (SD cards are 3.3V devices). It is "enough" that you are talking to an SD card using an SD card library. The SD card is really all the hardware there is - everything else is just interfacing fluff - completely transparent to the software.